# Import CSV and perform loop

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
Id  Appid
12i5r6  123
4524hu  123
r664hf  963
gjh6hg  963
```

Above is my CSV data.
Using PowerShell Please help me to run a loop where out of two similar app IDs it takes only 1 and since the IDs are different both the IDs should be stored  in a variable.

Comment: We don't write code for any one, we just help when someone gets doubt or error when they do it of their own. Have some attempts of your own, feel it and post that code here if you need help.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *specific* problem (in your code) do you need help with?